# Test if class extends specific class ArchUnit

Tags: java, archunit

Is there way to test that classes extends specific class in ArchUnit test?

I have 3 classes:

1. ClassA
2. ClassB which extends ClassA
3. ClassC which extends ClassB

I need to validate that ClassC extends ClassA. The following test

```
ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
    .that()
        .haveSimpleName("ClassC")
    .should()
        .beAssignableTo("ClassA")
    .check(classes);
```

fails with violation error

```
Architecture Violation [Priority: MEDIUM] - Rule 'classes that have simple name 'ClassC' should be assignable to ClassA' was violated (1 times):
Class <ClassC> is not assignable to ClassA in ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `beAssignableTo("ClassA")` if `ClassA` resides in the default package.

In general, you [have to use fully qualified class name](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html), i.e. `ClassA.class.getName()`.

If `ClassA` is available on the classpath, I'd use `beAssignableTo(ClassA.class)`.

Comment: @Gefest, did this answer solve your question? Merry Christmas!